# Is Null Utility method better implementation

Tags: java

I need to implement an `isNull()` utility method, that checks if any given object is `null` or empty.
I came up with a solution: see code below.

I know with recent version of Java the overhead of `instanceof` has been decreased and it is micro-optimization. This is my implementation to check `isNull`.

```
public static boolean isNull(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof String) {
        return ((String) object).length() == 0;
    } else if (object instanceof Object[]) {
        return ((Object[]) object).length == 0;
    } else if (object instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection) object).isEmpty();
    } else if (object instanceof Map) {
        return ((Map) object).isEmpty();
    } else {
        return object == null;
    }
}
```

Is there a better to do this?

Comment: None of those things are null, except the last case. Null is null, empty is empty. If you want something to check for null or empty, call it `isNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: The `isNull` name is misleading. `isNullOrEmpty` seems better.

Comment: If this is working code, it is better-suited to [codereview.se].

Comment: `isNullOrEmpty` is a bad idea, `isEmpty` is one thing and `isNull` is a different thing

Comment: @AndyTurner:  I'm extremely reluctant to say this should go to Code Review.  There doesn't seem to be enough code here to justify a full code review of it.  Also, there's no real guarantee of "working".

Comment: I tested this, it perfectly works. I would prefer to keep the logic to check both null and empty. Happy to rename it to isNullOrEmpty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would like to know any other better ways of doing this.

The better way of doing it is to use the APIs of those classes directly.

e.g. instead of:

```
isNull(someString)
isNull(someCollection)
```

use

```
someString == null || someString.isEmpty()
someCollection == null || someCollection.isEmpty()
```

This is more verbose, but has several advantages:

- If you silently treat emptiness and nullness as the same thing, you might be ignoring bugs in your code. The `null` case could be true only in error cases: you got this value from somewhere else, where you were expecting a non-null value, but you've got a programming bug.

  Instead, by testing for null explicitly, you are documenting your expectations of the code providing that null value. Or, you can omit it, documenting that you expected the value to be non-null.
- Your method is only able to correctly determine the "emptiness" of a string, a collection, an array of reference type or a map; if you use it on something else, where there is a defined notion of emptiness, the method will only tell you if it is null. By calling the class' API explicitly, you are able to determine the emptiness correctly.

  The flip side of this argument is that there is no such thing as "emptiness" for certain types, such as `Integer`. It doesn't make sense to consider whether these are empty, so you shouldn't be able to pass it into this method.

  An alternative approach to constrain the parameter to only be a string, reference type array, collection or map would be to provide overloads for just those types, e.g. `isNullOrEmpty(String)`, `isNullOrEmpty(Object[])` etc,  and not provide an overload taking `Object`.

But what if you've only got an `Object` reference, i.e. you don't know how to determine the emptiness? Well, an `Object` isn't very much use anyway. So you've got an empty or null `Object` reference. Great... and now what?

You've got to cast it to something else, unless you simply want to invoke `toString()` on it, or check if it is `null`. So, do that casting outside the method (e.g. using a chain of `instanceof` checks), and *then* you can do something meaningful with it.

Comment: Treated emptiness and nullness as the same thing as it is convenient for the caller...I agree should change the name of the method. if it is a custom 3rd party object. Just need to call Util.isNullOrEmpty(myObject)

Comment: @Morton you're missing the second point. This doesn't check for "is null or empty": it checks for "is null or is an empty string or is an empty reference array or is an empty collection or is an empty map". You don't correctly detect, say, an empty primitive array, an empty Iterable, or anything else which has a motion of emptiness not covered by these cases. As such, it is misleading for the method to imply it checks for the emptiness of its parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Well...you've already made a mistake:

> I need to implement an isNull() utility method, that check any given object is null or empty.

That makes the name `isNull` *horrifyingly* misleading.  You should change the name to reflect its intent, like `isNullOrEmpty`, or `isEmpty` (a-la Apache Commons Framework).

Now, on to the actual implementation.  It depends on what you want this method to respect.

- If you want to respect empty collections, that's reasonable - and doable with a cast to `((Collection)object).isEmpty()`.
- If you want to respect empty arrays, I personally wouldn't recommend this since an empty array is *utterly useless* regardless of what anyone tells you.
- If you want to respect `String`s as well, then you should leverage a simpler check - `"".equals(object)`.  This will return false if it's *not* a `String`, is `null`, or is a `String` and is not empty.

The actual *implementation* of these things, I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: "any given object is null or empty" The thing I think is misleading is that this doesn't work correctly for *any* object: it works OK for any object which is a string, a collection, an array of reference type or a map. It doesn't work for anything else which has a notion of emptiness.

Comment: @AndyTurner:  While that's actually pedantic, it's very, very true.  A custom object which isn't any of those would not register as being empty with this utility.